# How to implement a multithreading with queue in a wave generation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I have a code to generate sine wave of 1 Hz to 7 Hz with sampling rate of 1000 Hz. The requirement is that to generate a multithreading program where for loop of 10 iteration is used to get values of sine waves. Each time the loop gets 100 points thus executing the for loop 10 times will produce 100 x10 = 1000 points. The thousand points must be stored in a queue and thus transfering the queue value to the next thread.

Here is my code which generates a Sine wave points

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def get_values_for_frequency(freq):
    # sampling information
    omega = 2*np.pi*freq # angular frequency for sine waves with amplitude 1
    t_vec = np.linspace(0,1,num=1000,endpoint=True) # time 
    y = np.sin(omega*t_vec) #sine wave generation
    return y
#columns are created for sine wave frequencies
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['1Hz','2Hz', '3Hz', '4Hz', '5Hz', '6Hz', '7Hz'])
df['1Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(1))
df['2Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(2))
df['3Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(3))
df['4Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(4))
df['5Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(5))
df['6Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(6))
df['7Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(7))
df = df.round(decimals = 6)                  #Round a table values in DataFrame to3 decimal places
df['1Hz']=(2**15) *df['1Hz']                 #values are converted into int16 equivalent
df['2Hz']=(2**15) *df['2Hz']
df['3Hz']=(2**15) *df['3Hz']
df['4Hz']=(2**15) *df['4Hz']
df['5Hz']=(2**15) *df['5Hz']
df['6Hz']=(2**15) *df['6Hz']
df['7Hz']=(2**15) *df['7Hz']
df = df.astype(np.int16)                        #converting float datatype to int16
arr=df.to_numpy(dtype='int16')    

  The arr numpy array has the values for sine waves 1000X7 rows and  columns.
```

The requirement is to implement it as multithreaded program where the below part must be executed 10 times and each times 100 values must be collected and after 10 loops ,all the values must be aggregated and send to through queue for next processing.

```
def get_values_for_frequency(freq):
omega = 2*np.pi*freq # angular frequency for sine waves with amplitude 1
t_vec = np.linspace(0,1,num=1000,endpoint=True) # time 
y = np.sin(omega*t_vec) #sine wave generation
return y
#columns are created for sine wave frequencies
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['1Hz','2Hz', '3Hz', '4Hz', '5Hz', '6Hz', '7Hz'])
df['1Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(1))
df['2Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(2))
df['3Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(3))
df['4Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(4))
df['5Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(5))
df['6Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(6))
df['7Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(7))
```

when I try to implement , I got only 100x 7 i.e.last iteration value. Could anyone guide me to solve this

here is my code which I tried.

```
import threading
import numpy as np
from queue import Queue
import pandas as pd

def get_values_for_frequency(freq):
    omega = 2*np.pi*freq 
    t_vec = np.linspace(origin,end,num=100,endpoint=True) 
    y = np.sin(omega*t_vec)                              
    return y
    
def thread_task(in_q):
    global df, df1,end,origin
    df= pd.DataFrame(columns =['1Hz','2Hz', '3Hz', '4Hz', '5Hz', '6Hz', '7Hz'])
    end=1/10
    origin=0
    for _ in range(10):
        df['1Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(1))
        df['2Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(2))
        df['3Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(3))
        df['4Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(4))
        df['5Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(5))
        df['6Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(6))
        df['7Hz']=pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(7))
        origin=end
        end+=end
    df = df.round(decimals = 6)                  
    df['1Hz']=(2**15) *df['1Hz']                 
    df['2Hz']=(2**15) *df['2Hz']
    df['3Hz']=(2**15) *df['3Hz']
    df['4Hz']=(2**15) *df['4Hz']
    df['5Hz']=(2**15) *df['5Hz']
    df['6Hz']=(2**15) *df['6Hz']
    df['7Hz']=(2**15) *df['7Hz']
    df = df.astype(np.int16) 
    in_q.put(df)
def output(out_q):
    while True:
        print(out_q.get())
def main_task():
    global df
    global df1
    global end
    global origin
    df= pd.DataFrame(columns =['1Hz','2Hz', '3Hz', '4Hz', '5Hz', '6Hz', '7Hz'])
    df1=pd.DataFrame()
    q = Queue()
    lock = threading.Lock()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_task, args=(q,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=output, args=(q,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main_task()
```

Comment: Please re-read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you actually have it. Also, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose the problem in more detail. For example, if you call `get_values_for_frequency` separately - without trying to create the Dataframe - do you get the results you expect? You mention multithreading, but you don't show that code. Does the code work single-threaded? If the problem only occurs with multithreading, then we have to see that code to help with it.

Comment: Thanks @Karl Knechtel. I have added the program which I have tried